# Javascript for Cognos to display all pages of report in iframe

Tags: javascript, cognos-10

I need to display a cognos reports on the display screen and the reports need to be refreshed at a given interval of time.

1) one off the cognos report had 6 pages in it, and i need to show all the six pages one after the other, and it should go to the next report and in the same way it has to display all the pages in the all report.

presently i am using iframe to display multiple cognos reports, but the show stopper is i am unable to display all pages of the cognos report, as it is showing only 1st page of the report.

script to display multiple cognos reports.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var slideimages = new Array();
            slideimages[0] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[1] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[2] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%202%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%202&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[3] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20INDIRECT%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20INDIRECT%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[4] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LATE%20PICKS%20SCOREBOARD%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LATE%20PICKS%20SCOREBOARD&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[5] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20CASES%20TO%20PICK%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20CASES%20TO%20PICK&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[6] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20LETDOWNS%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20LETDOWNS&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[7] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REPICKS%20PENDING%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REPICKS%20PENDING&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[8] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20MEZZANINE%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20MEZZANINE%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[9] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20SECTION%20AND%20REPORT%20GROUP%20SUMMARY%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20SECTION%20AND%20REPORT%20GROUP%20SUMMARY&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[10] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20TOWER%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20TOWER%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";

// style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" frameborder="0" 
// style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"
    </script>
</head>
```

body
            {
                margin:   0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

```
        #iframe1
        {
            height:   100%;
            left:     0px;
            position: absolute;
            top:      0px;
            width:    100%;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <iframe id="slide" src="" frameborder="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var step=0
        function slideit(){
         document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step]
         if (step<slideimages.length-1)
         step++
         else
          step=0
         setTimeout("slideit()",20000)
        }
        slideit()

    </script>

</body>
```

Can anybody help me giving a solution.

Kind Regards,
Anil R G

Answer (score 0):

This is how you advance to the next page via JavaScript and the Cognos JS API:

```
var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
report.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.NEXT);
```

The API is provided in Cognos BI versions 10.2 and above.

I would create a function in each of the target reports like so:

```
function navigate(action) {
    var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
    report.sendRequest(action);
}
```

Then I'd call that function from the main code:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('slide');
iframe.navigate(cognos.Report.Action.NEXT);
```

This would advance the report currently in the iFrame by one page.

The challenge comes with looping through the pages. You'd have to know how many pages each report had somehow. If the reports have a fixed, known number of pages then no problem. I'd create an array of objects to store both the source and the number of pages:

```
var reports = [];
reports.push(new Report('http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=true',4));
reports.push(new Report('http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true',9));
...

function Report (src,pagecount) {
    this.src = src;
    this.pagecount = pagecount;
    this.currentpage = 1;
    this.advanceCount = function () {
        if (this.currentpage == this.pagecount) {
            this.currentpage = 1;
        } else {
            this.currentpage++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could loop through the reports array, changing the source as you did before and then using currentpage and pagecount of the current instance to determine how many times to advance the page. You call the iframe.navigate(cognos.Report.Action.NEXT); the correct number of times and call advanceCount() on the report object to increment the page counter.

For reference, all the actions you can pass to the navigate() function are as follows:

```
cognos.Report.Action.NEXT
cognos.Report.Action.BACK
cognos.Report.Action.REPROMPT
cognos.Report.Action.CANCEL
cognos.Report.Action.FINISH
```